# mysql returning nothing after i select another table using a value i just inserted

Tags: mysql, flask

I am using the **Flask server** side to communicate with a MySQL community server schema. I am trying to insert an image into the database with the image binary, caption of image, `userid`, etc. I then get the `photo_id` of the image I just inserted using `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Photos`, where all the `photo_id`s are primary keys, and they auto-increment.

Here is the schema of `Photos`(where the images are being stored)

```
CREATE TABLE Photos(
 photo_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
 caption VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 imgdata LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
 albums_id INTEGER,
 user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (photo_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (albums_id)
 REFERENCES Albums (albums_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
 REFERENCES Users (user_id)
);
```

There is no issue with the albums or user ids, and those are not involved in this function.

Here is my relevant code (in python):

```
# this is simply to get and read the image binary
imgfile = request.files["photo"]
caption = request.form.get("caption")
photo_data = imgfile.read()
cursor = conn.cursor()
# this statement executes fine because the image shows up
# on another page where i list all images
cursor.execute(
    """INSERT INTO Photos (imgdata, user_id, caption, albums_id) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)""",
    (photo_data, uid, caption, idOfAlbum),
)
conn.commit()

# get the photoid we just inserted
# by counting rows since photo_id is autoincrement
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Photos")
conn.commit()

# this prints correctly (eg, if there are 9 photos this will print 9 based on autoincrement)
photoID = cursor.fetchone()[0]
print("photoid uploaded is :", photoID)

# this should retrieve the caption of the image i just uploaded
cursor.execute(
    "SELECT Photos.caption from Photos WHERE Photos.photo_id = '{0}'".format(
        photoID
    )
)
conn.commit()
# this always prints out "()" for some reason, when theres clearly a caption
# since it shows up on another page
print("PHOTO CAPTION i just uploaded: ", cursor.fetchall())
```

I feel my approach is naive but I do not understand why I cannot fetch the caption using the `photoID` of an image, I just inserted and committed.

Comment: `get the photoid we just inserted
        # by counting rows since photo_id is autoincrement` this is ill-advised. As an obvious example, what if a photo is deleted?

Comment: This is true, but for the sake of the question, i never deleted nor refreshed the schema and ive watched the photoid print out incrementally each time. is there anything else im doing wrong?